# How can I start and stop impulse animation from a button in TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, swift

There is a UIImage inside the MainViewController as seen in the picture. There is also a button in TabBarViewController. When I press the button, I want the impulse animation I wrote for the UIView to start and stop.When i click to play button animation is not started. How can I do this?
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1DXc.png)

Here is my code;

```
class MainViewObject: UIView {
   //Center Image View Container
    lazy var centerContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 113
        view.backgroundColor = Colors.lightOrangeColor
        return view
    }()
}

class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {
   var object: MainViewObject!

   //Create Play Button
    let middleButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 32, y: -8, width: 65, height: 65))
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        btn.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
        btn.backgroundColor = Colors.mainColor
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        btn.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        btn .addTarget(self, action:#selector(menuButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside
        return btn
    }()
    
    //Play Pause Button Function
    @objc func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        if sender.isSelected {
            middleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            playRadio()
            pulseAnimationStart()
        }else{
            middleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            player!.pause()
            pulseAnimationStop()
        }
    }
}

extension TabbarViewController { 
   //Main Page Main Image Pulse Animation Start
    func pulseAnimationStart() {
        let fadingAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadingAnimation.fromValue = 1
        fadingAnimation.toValue = 0

        let expandingAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        expandingAnimation.fromValue = 1
        expandingAnimation.toValue = 1.1

        let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup.animations = [expandingAnimation,
                                     fadingAnimation]
        animationGroup.duration = 1.5
        animationGroup.repeatCount = .infinity
        self.object.centerContainerView.layer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")
    }

   //Main Page Main Image Pulse Animation Stop
   func pulseAnimationStop() {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0) {
         self.object.centerContainerView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to call addTarget on your button with menuButtonAction: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget

Comment: What is a guy named 'self.object' and where does it come from?

Comment: Hi @Rob actually addtarget is working. When i call animation function in uiviewcontroller it works.  But tabbarviewcontroller doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi @El Tomato ‘self.object’ is coming from ‘ var object: MainViewObject! ’. I did edit My code.